# Select all rows that matches any from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Get all `Users` from first table that have any word matching in another table;

I have `Users` table that contain, among others, column with `FullName`, that column is `Full Text Search` Indexed. Sometimes first "word" is name, sometimes first "word" is surname from the `FullName` column;

Like John Smith or Smith John.

And another table that have just local firstname.

I want to get all Users that have matching local name.

```
Users Table:
John Smith
Rebecca Mark
Maria Anna
Lance Maria 
Emilia Clark
Snow John
Natalie Butler

Name Table:
Maria
Smith

Result of Query:
John Smith
Maria Anna
Lance Maria
Snow John
```

I can do only single Name with Contains function.

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE CONTAINS(FullName, 'John');
```

But I need it for each row in `Name Table`.

Every row from `FullName` contains any of Name Table... But in SQL Query.

Comment: You can do an inner join using a like statement on the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid a case where you are search for `'Maria'` and the matching name is `'Marianne'`, 
 check for 2 conditions: (1) the name is at the start or (2) at the end of `FullName`:

(1):

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM Users u INNER JOIN Name n
ON 
  u.FullName LIKE concat(n.name, ' %') 
  OR 
  u.FullName LIKE concat('% ', n.name)
```

or (2):

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM Users u INNER JOIN Name n
ON 
  concat(' ', u.FullName, ' ') LIKE concat('% ', n.name, ' %')
```

Answer (score 1):

use join and like for matching

```
select u.* from table_users u join table_name b on
             u.users like concat('%',b.name,'%')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists` for this:

```
select u.*
from users u
where exists (select 1
              from nametable n
              where u.fullname like '%' + n.name + '%'
             );
```

If you want to avoid partial matches on names, then take the delimiters into account:

```
where exists (select 1
              from nametable n
              where ' ' + u.fullname + ' ' like '% ' + n.name + ' %'
             );
```

Comment: Problem with that is John is matches with Johnson

Comment: I can hack it with one or statement with spaces on start OR on the end of word. Like this: '% ' + n.name Or n.name ' %'.

Comment: Thank you. It works good, I must accept firs working answer. Up. You'll get upvote. ;)